# Solace messages from embedded application Arduino or Intel Edison?

Tags: c++, arduino, solace, intel-edison

just as the title says, someone of you has had luck integrating Solace messages from an embedded application. I could only find their API to be used under an operating system, not for standalone applications.

Is there any stack or libraries to do the task from a 32bit microcontroller under C/C++?

Comment: Sorry, this type of question is explicitly disallowed on SO. Instead, please describe what you've tried to solve the problem and what issues you had.

Comment: so then what should I do? Solace website is pointing to me to this forum to ask questions, I did that

Answer (score 1):

You could always use MQTT from your embedded platform to connect to Solace.

Different endpoints can use different messaging protocols, so a telemetry reading going in via MQTT can be seamlessly fanned out over JMS and AMQP to different backends.

Comment: do you know if there are any open source library to use MQTT?to use it on the code for my firmware?

Comment: I don't know much about embedded development, but I though that's where MQTT originally came from :-) Quick web search gave me this: https://github.com/256dpi/arduino-mqtt Also mqtt.org has a link to a list of libraries: https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/libraries

Answer (score 1):

Solace PubSub+ Message Brokers natively support the OASIS MQTT 3.1.1 standard to meet the needs of connected devices and mobile applications. MQTT is a lightweight messaging protocol specifically designed for applications where a small code footprint is required, such as for embedded applications.

There are many free MQTT client libraries available for use. For example, an Arduino specific MQTT client is available here:
https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/